# egghead.io webpack angular tutorial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, webpack

I have problems with the tutorial webpack-angular from egghead.io. I'm in the step 3 "ES6 with Babel".

I need your help because I would like to resolve it.

I'm following your tutorial and I'm freezing in this step:

This is the message Chrome devTool where I got an error

...........

```
bundle.js:17416 Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:17416__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20Object.defineProperty.value @ bundle.js:66(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:69
Navigated to http://localhost:8080/
```

The directive 'Hello webpack!' is not showing

.........

This is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-angular",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Example of using webpack",
  "main": "app/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\"",
    "start": "node node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base app"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "webpack",
    "angular",
    "egghead.io"
  ],
  "author": "Pablo B.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

................

This is the webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/app',
  entry:  './index.js',
  output:{
    path: __dirname + '/app',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module:{
    loaders:[
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader'}
    ]
  }
}
```

And this is the result of the terminal after running the npm start command.

webpack npm start

> > webpack-angular@1.0.0 start /home/pablo/Documents/tutoriales/webpack
> >     node node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base app
>
> http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/ webpack result is served
>   from / content is served from
>   /home/pablo/Documents/tutoriales/webpack/app [BABEL] Note: The code
>   generator has deoptimised the styling of
>   "/home/pablo/Documents/tutoriales/webpack/node_modules/angular/angular.js"
>   as it exceeds the max of "500KB". Hash: 69ba24ec3148fc14b2e7 Version:
>   webpack 2.2.1 Time: 3976ms
>       Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names bundle.js  1.11 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main chunk    {0} bundle.js (main) 1.1 MB [entry] [rendered]
>       [0] ./app/directives/index.js 69 bytes {0} [built]
>       [1] ./~/angular/index.js 47 bytes {0} [built]
>       [2] ./app/directives/kcd-hello.js 391 bytes {0} [built]
>       [3] ./~/angular/angular.js 1.1 MB {0} [built]
>       [4] ./app/index.js 114 bytes {0} [built] webpack: bundle is now VALID.

Any Idea?

The main problem is to show the directive "Hello Webpack!". Why do I get the webpack require error?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself. I change the way to do it.

Before:

```
const angular = require('angular'); 
const ngModule = angular.module('app',[]); 
require('./directives')(ngModule);
```

After:

```
const angular = require('angular'); 
const ngModule = angular.module('app',[]);
require('./directives').default(ngModule);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you inject babel into your application properly? Sometimes this has to do with the node module name not resolving correctly. It looks like you have all the required ES6 components.

Comment: This is the way that I am using BAbel in the index.js file `export default ngModule => {
  require('./kcd-hello')(ngModule);
};`

Comment: `module.exports = function(ngModule){
  ngModule.directive('kcdHello',function(){
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'E';
    directive.scope = {};
    directive.templateUrl= "directives/kcd-hello.html",
    directive.controllerAs = "vm";
    directive.controller = function(){
      var vm = this;
        vm.greeting = "Hello Webpack!";
    }
    return directive;
  })
}`

Comment: Should I change all the ways that I am using module.exports by export default ngModule???? The tutorial just changes this file.

Comment: I fixed it myself. I change the way to do it. before: `const angular = require('angular');
const ngModule = angular.module('app',[]);
require('./directives')(ngModule);` after `const angular = require('angular');
const ngModule = angular.module('app',[]);
require('./directives').default(ngModule);
`